# Load item from DB when clicking on next button carousel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need carousel that load items from DB only when clicking on next button not when page load.
please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Keyword to search here is `ajax`. Familiarize yourself with the concept, then use jQuery `ajax()` or `post()` functions.

Comment: thank u so much i'll try with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to using the PHP,SQL,jQuery(AJAX)

PHP:

```
//This will output using JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
$getDBData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getDBData)){

$id = $rows['id'] //ID from the DB;
$name = $rows['name'] //Name from the DB too;

$JSONfeedback = array(
    "id" => "$id",
    "name" => "$name"
  );

  echo json_encode($JSONfeedback);

}
```

JS:

```
$.post('thatPHP.php',function(feedback){
  console.log('This is my id: ' + feedback.id);
  console.log('This is my name: ' + feedback.name);
});
```